# Critérios usados para levar uma pergunta à página principal

Tags: debate, perguntas, comunidade

Ao acessar a página inicial do [SO-pt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) é exibido a sequência de perguntas feitas pelos usuários, além das perguntas são mostradas alguns valores referentes à pergunta, tais como quantidade de votos, número de respostas, visitas feitas, os assuntos relacionados e quem realizou a pergunta da seguinte maneira: 
**perguntados** *[xx]* **minutos atrás** *[nome_do_usuário] [reputação]*
porém, algumas vezes, nos é exibido da seguinte maneira: 
**modificada** *[xx]* **minutos atrás Comunidade♦ 1** 
Segue exemplo abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E ao acessar a pergunta é exibido uma **div**isão amarelada com a seguinte mensagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber quais critérios são usados para uma determinada pergunta ser levada à página principal pela *Comunidade♦*, qualquer informação adicional seria bem vinda!